# Showing current/dynmaic url in react tab

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome

Simple problem which I cannot seem to find the answer to. Currently I have built a website with react and when a user opens a new tab it shows the same favicon, image and hard coded title on every tab. I simply wish to do as stackoverflow, and may other web pages and dynamically show the page title in the tab.
[image]

My current index.html in the react app just has the hard-coded title. Does anyone know how to change this to show the current web url ? Thanks!

```
 <title>My Website </title>
```

Answer (score 1):

this function will change the title of your page .

```
function setTitle (arg){
   document.title = arg ;
 }
```

then in your component you can do like below :

```
export default function Component() {

setTitle("your title") ;

 function setTitle (arg){
   document.title = arg ;
 }

}
```

Comment: thank you. Now just to find somewhere in the root level to make this happen on all comp. changes. you rock. +1.

Comment: you can use this in the parent component , for example a landing page that has many other components in it .

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for anyone else looking for this. Simply remove the title. The hard coded title did not allow the page to show dynamically in the title. After removing them the react-router route renders in the tab.